# Redirecting website using RewriteRules without changing the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website/platform that has many templates/versions which loads dynamic content based on the query string input.

Based on my clients requests, whenever we visit sub.samplewebsite.com we should display content from sampleweb2.com/go.php... without redirecting the browser.

**It worked for the index** by adding the below rules to httpd.conf file, however when i tried to do the same for thankyou.php, it wouldn't work... Can you help here?

Also if you could mention how to enable pretty urls (/thankyou/ instead of thankyou.php) would be great. Thanks!

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.samplewebsite.com
 RewriteRule index.php http://www.sampleweb2.com/go.php?template=3&version=7&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]
 RewriteRule thankyou.php http://www.sampleweb2.com/thankyou.php?template=3&version=7&%{QUERY_STRING} [P]
```